# Animations are clipped to ViewGroup bounds in Android 4.3 and below?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, viewgroup, android-viewgroup

I'm working on a custom `ViewGroup` which draws some animations in the `dispatchDraw()` method.

I came across this in my Google search: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/dZ0Yxjz3v7o

And I have set `clipChildren="false"` inside my XML to both the parent and the grandparent view of my custom `ViewGroup`. However, this fixed the clipping of the animations drawing on Android 4.3 and above. Android 4.0 - 4.3 still clips the View animations to its bounds.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just done some trial and error and found a solution to my own problem :) (Don't you just love it when this happens??)

Basically where I was calling my `invalidate()` on my custom view in order to draw the animation, I need to also call `((View) getParent()).invalidate()` in order to invalidate the parent so that it forces a draw on it.

I guess later versions of Android are smart about this, however for anything below 4.3 I needed to explicitly invalidate the parent in order to draw the animation beyond the bounds of my custom view.

Hope this helps someone that ran into the same problem.